# Android change button params on click then reset

Tags: android

I have a small button and when clicked it will expand to width:match_parent. When clicked again I want the button parameters from the xml to be applied. Its a custom button so its not as easy as just resizing the width.

My current code looks like:

```
btnBottomSheetTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                mSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                btnBottomSheetTitle.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 150));
                btnBottomSheetTitle.setCornerRadius(0);
            } else {
                mSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
               
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You have style for button You can set it programmatically. Before setting `setOnClickListener` save current button's `LayoutParams`

```
final android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams savedParams = btnBottomSheetTitle.getLayoutParams();
```

In Your `else` add:

```
btnBottomSheetTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_style);
btnBottomSheetTitle.setLayoutParams(savedParams);
```